# Is it possible to pass ModelExpression to a TagHelper?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

We can get a `ModelExpression` using this property in a TagHelper:

```
[HtmlAttributeName("asp-for")]
public ModelExpression For { get; set; }
```

I somehow managed* to have a ViewModel which has a `ModelExpression` property:

```
public class TemplateViewModel
{
    public ModelExpression For { get; set; }
}
```

Every time I try to pass it, the Model expression is `For` from `TemplateViewModel`, not the real Expression which is stored into `For`:

```
@model TemplateViewModel
<input asp-for="@Model.For" class="form-control"/>
```

Above results in:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="For" name="For" value="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ModelExpression" />
```

I expected, the input, which is described by the `ModelExpression` instead of literally a `ModelExpression` for the `ModelExpression`.

<sub><sub>*since I want to have a Template View for an TagHelper using `IHtmlHelper::PartialView()`. This example is heavy minimized. My main motivation is to create a single `<form-group for="" />` TagHelper, which is generating a [Bootstrap Form Group](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#horizontal-form).</sub></sub>

Answer (score 3):

`ModelExpression` is handled as a special case in the [Razor Compiler](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/blob/11c5293862318091dd86d07b03ad57a531954116/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Extensions/ModelExpressionPass.cs#L28), so this isn't going to work directly. Since the compiler is open source, you could suggest a patch to ignore cases where the property is itself a `ModelExpression`. In the mean time, you're going to need to use a different type of property in your tag helper, to help you get a reference to the actual `ModelExpression`. Perhaps `public Func<ModelExpression> ForAccessor { get; set; }`?