# ASP.NET Core MVC : using custom tag helpers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-7.0, tag-helpers

I have a custom tag helper defined like so:

```
public class TextQuestionTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private readonly HtmlHelper _htmlHelper;

    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-for")]
    public ModelExpression For { get; set; }

    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }

    public TextQuestionTagHelper(IHtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        _htmlHelper = htmlHelper as HtmlHelper;
    }

    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        var partial = await _htmlHelper.PartialAsync(
            "Tags/TextQuestion",
            new TextQuestionViewModel
            {
                Question = Question,
                Description = Description
            });
    }
}
```

In the template `Tags/TextQuestion` I have:

```
@model TextQuestionViewModel

<p>@Model.Question</p>
<p>@Model.Description</p>
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m)
```

Notice how I have a property `For` I'm wondering how to do I map this to the `TextBoxFor` inside my custom template and then render that view for the tag helper? I can't find any examples online

Answer (score 0):

First define your taghelper

```
//add a maxlength validation for example
[HtmlTargetElement("input", Attributes = "asp-for")]
public class TextQuestionTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public override int Order { get; } = int.MaxValue;

    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-for")]
    public ModelExpression For { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        base.Process(context, output);

        ...
    }

    private static int GetMaxLength(IReadOnlyList<object> validatorMetadata)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then in the model

```
public class TextQuestionViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Question")]
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Foo cannot be longer than 5 characters.")]
    public string Question { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Question")]
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Foo cannot be longer than 10 characters.")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
}
```

In the view

```
<input asp-for="Question" data-val="true" />
```

Remember to add the taghelper in _ViewImports

> @addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
>
> @addTagHelper *, yourProject

The input limit is set

[image]

And the page

[image]

Comment: You've not answered the question, I wanted to pass the model to the partial view which renders a TextBoxFor and use the properties of the model there

Comment: Sorry to misunderstand your question.  I believe this is exactly what you need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55446449/pass-modelexpression-from-a-tag-helper-to-a-partial-view. Please let me know if there is still something wrong.